# Javascript new Operator inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is a the simplest function:

```
module.exports = function Dummy(id) {
    this.id = id;

    this.delay = function() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // Do some stuff async
            // once done
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate a few instances of this `Dummy()` class inside a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var id = "id_" + i;
    var dummy = new Dummy(id);

    dummy
        .delay()
        .then(function () {
            console.log(dummy.id);
        });
}
```

However, all of these print `id_2`; its as though the instant `dummy` is overwritten, even though I am instantiating the variable `var dummy` every time inside the `for` loop.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closure problem with the variable called *dummy* inside the *then function*. The value will be the last iterated because every iteration of the for will override the previous one. It means that when the *then function* is **executed asynchronously** (due to the promise you are using) the value of the *dummy* var will be the last value assigned during the loop.

To fix it I suggest to simply do this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function (id) { //Creates a simple new scope
        var dummy = new Dummy(id);

        dummy
            .delay()
            .then(function () {
                console.log(dummy.id);
            });
    })("id_" + i);
}
```

There are lots of ways to fix this but I think that is the simplest for your current code.

As you may noticed, for every for iteration I have created a new scope. When the *then function* is executed, it will access to the *dummy* var in that scope.

Comment: You need to love javascript, if there's a closure issue, simply add another function. Value will not be last, but 'current'.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you complaining about my solution? As I have said there are lots of ways to fix this problem. Actually, I usually don't have it because my architecture avoid this kind of problems. Scoping in JavaScript is just an awesome feature, but it is not the only.

Comment: And YES. I LOVE javascript :) No problem to admit it :)

Comment: Didnt complain, gave you an upvote as well ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's because when `console.log` happens, dummy is `id_2`.

```
.then(function () {
  console.log(dummy.id);
});
```

The promises will be queued and resolve after the execution of the for loop. Once the promise resolves `dummy` is the value of the last iteration.